# How to select jQuery children without reference to parent

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm parsing a large XML object, and I want to farm out individual pieces as standalone objects--that is, these new objects should contain no references to the parent (source) XML.

However.

If I construct this code:

```
var a = $('<parent><child>Exclude Parent</child></parent>');        
var b = $('>child', a);  
var c = a.children('child'); 

console.log(a.children('child').parent());                  
console.log(b.parent());                   
console.log(c.parent());
```

Each of these still maintains a parent reference. I would expect var b and c to be independent objects, but they are not. I *could* convert the child XML to string and then recast as a jQuery object, but that seems both expensive and unnecessary.

How can I instance a new variable which represents *only* the XML of the jQuery selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to clone them:

```
var c = a.children('child').clone();

console.log( c.parent().length );  // 0
```

You're creating new nodes apart from the original structure, leaving the original intact.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

You'd do something like this:

```
var a_kids = a.find(selector).detach();
```

This will remove the elements from their original parent document though.

Comment: This is excellent to know. In this case, clone() is the method I need.